# In RDBMS, is the key used for building the index for a database always the primary key?

Tags: database

1. How do we specify which key is used for building the index for a
   database in SQL?
2. In most if not all RDBMS, is the search key used for building the index for a database **always**
   the primary key?

   From Database Management Systems, 3rd Edition, by Raghu
   Ramakrishnan, and Johannes Gehrke

   > In  principle,  we  can  use  any  key,  not  just  the  primary 
   >   key,  to  refer  to  a  tuple.  However,  using  the  primary  key  is
   >   preferable  because  it  is  what the DBMS  expects  - this is  the
   >   significance  of designating a  particular  candidate key  as  a 
   >   primary key  and optimizes  for.  For  example, the DBMS  **may** create
   >   an index with the primary key fields  as  the search key,  to make the
   >   retrieval of a  tuple given  its  primary key  value efficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That depends on which RDBMS you are using. It will be something like
   `CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(key_name)`.
2. YES and NO.

   a) If you are creating a table, and generally the RDBMS will create the index for this table using the primary key you specify in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. If you don't specify a primary key, RDBMS will help you choose an unique and non-null key, OR create an internal key (probably an int type) as primary key for this table.

   b) Sometimes, according to the query pattern, you may find some keys other than primary key are used frequently (in `where` clause for example), then it is good to build new indexes using these keys.

Comment: Thanks. ' If you don't specify a primary key, RDBMS will create an internal key (probably an int type) as primary key for this table.' Is the internal key created by RDBMS not any key in the table?

Comment: I think both solutions are adopted in mainstream RDBMSs. For example, MySQL chooses the first non-null unique key in your table as primary key. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to your question:

1. I'm trying to interpret your questions. Perhaps what you need to understand is that there can be more than one index into a table?

Let's say you have a *Customers* table with 3 columns, *CustomerID*, *LastName*, and *FirstName*.

You create an index using a specific `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE` command where you specify the specific columns you want to have included in the index. You do not have to have the primary key as part of an index; for example, you may create an index on a table of customers by their last name and first name to speed name searches while still having a different primary key like customerID. Here's some SQL-like syntax.

```
CREATE INDEX customer_name_idx ON Customers(LastName, FirstName)
```

This index doesn't include any primary keys nor does it require a primary key to function properly. Internally, it will likely point to some internal row IDs that only the DBMS cares about.

2. I'm trying to understand what you mean here as well.

A DBMS can return a result regardless of the presence of an index; an index just makes it more efficient if your query matches up nicely with an index.

Designating a column as a primary key provides benefits such as enforced uniqueness, and possibly some performance benefits for enforcing other foreign key constraints.

As your quote says though, there is no written rule that says a primary key must also be an index. MySQL, and probably many other DMBSes, creates an index automatically on the table's primary key as it makes sense to do so from a technical level.

Anyway, I hope this makes sense and I hope I can clarify better if you have other questions.