# Does PostgreSQL create an internal key (probably an int type) as primary key for a table without a primary key specified?

Tags: postgresql

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/40597571/3284469

> If you don't specify a primary key, RDBMS will help you choose an unique and non-null key, OR **create an internal key (probably an int type) as primary key for this table**.

Could you give some examples for the "OR" case, where a RDBMS (PostgreSQL in particular, and possibly also MySQL or SQL Server) create an "internal key (probably an int type) as primary key" for a table without a primary key specified?

Does PostgreSQL have something similar to [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181742/)?

Thanks.

Comment: No, Postgres does not create such a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for Postgres:

  From ["5.4. System Columns"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html):

  > `oid`
  >
  > The object identifier (object ID) of a row. This column is only present if the table was created using `WITH OIDS`, or if the [default_with_oids](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS) configuration variable was set at the time. This column is of type `oid` (same name as the column); see [Section 8.18](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) for more information about the type.

  and

  > `ctid`
  >
  > The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the `ctid` can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's `ctid` will change if it is updated or moved by `VACUUM FULL`. Therefore `ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

  Both come close to what you're searching for but have restrictions as you can read in the documentation. So, as the manual states, using a user-defined PK is the better choice.
- for SQL Server:

  There is the undocumented pseudo column `%%physloc%%`. It describes the physical location of a row. That, however, might be subject to change if the row gets physically moved for whatever reason. And it's undocumented, that is, its behavior might change any time between releases or even just patches or it might be removed completely without further notice. So using a user-defined PK is the better choice here either.

Comment: The `ctid` is **not**  a replacement of a "primary key". It can and will change during the lifetime of a row .